# How to enforce the method signature of a function at compile time

Tags: kotlin, reflection, functional-interface

I have a usecase where through reflection I invoke specific functions that are annotated uniquely.
Here below MyClass and functionName have already been identified due to their annotation and are getting invoked.

```
MyClass.javaClass?.kotlin?.memberProperties?.find { function ->
        function == functionName
    }?.call(MyClass, params)
```

My concern is since these functions are written separately how do I ensure that these functions are always of the expected signature i.e. accepts a specific set of params that I define, because if not they would end up failing at runtime.

Is there a way to enforce a method signature contract through annotation?

The current approach I could come up with is to define a functional interface

```
fun interface MyHandler{ handle(params) }
```

and then create properties(rather than functions) that necessarily implement this functional interface (I'm hoping I will be able to filter properties that implement an interface)

```
var handler1 = MyHandler {params-> println("BL first $params")}
var handler2 = MyHandler {params-> println("BL second $params")}
```

But I do not know how to invoke such properties through reflection.

Comment: This is but one illustration of why reflection should be a last resort… (I've nothing against it, in its place — but that place is much more restricted than quite a few SO questions seem to assume.) — If you have a functional interface, then I'm guessing you can cast directly to that and avoid reflection entirely…? If so, then that sounds like a good approach.

Comment: I think what you want is known as 'duck typing'. This difficult, but not impossible. Try searching for 'duck typing Kotlin' or 'duck typing Java' https://gist.github.com/mikehearn/0313f4a2751f6929e8d7